# Server side rendering react js, typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, typescript, server-side-rendering

I am trying to convert my react js project implemented with typescript from Client Side Rendering to Server Side Rendering.

I have the following:

client/tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

server/tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "../",
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

webpack.common.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './src/index.tsx'),
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use:[
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use:['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf|svg|)$/,
                type: 'asset/inline'
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './build'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './public/index.html')
        })
    ]
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "giglink",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "eslint": "^8.55.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "feather-icons-react": "^0.6.2",
    "flag-icon-css": "^4.1.7",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
    "i18next": "^23.7.7",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^7.2.0",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^2.4.2",
    "i18next-http-middleware": "^3.5.0",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.5",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.32",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-feather": "^2.0.10",
    "react-i18next": "^13.5.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.12.0",
    "react-images-viewer": "^1.7.1",
    "react-modal-video": "^2.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.18.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.9.0",
    "react-select": "^5.8.0",
    "react-spinners": "^0.13.8",
    "sass": "^1.69.5",
    "tiny-slider": "^2.9.4",
    "tiny-slider-react": "^0.5.7",
    "typescript": "^5.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --exec \"./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack/webpack.config.js --env env=prod\"",
    "ssr": "node server/server.js",
    "buildSsr": "rm -rf && cd server && tsc",
    "start": "set PORT=5000 && react-scripts start",
    "build": "set PORT=5000 && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.1",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.10",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^20.10.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.40",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.17",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@types/react-modal-video": "^1.2.3",
    "@types/react-scroll": "^1.8.10",
    "@types/tiny-slider-react": "^0.3.8",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.13.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.13.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "postcss-import": "15.1.0",
    "postcss-nesting": "^12.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack": "^5.89.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  }
}
```

under client directory which is src/App.tsx:

```
export const App: FunctionComponent = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        document.documentElement.lang = i18next?.language;
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute("dir", "ltr");
        document.documentElement.classList.add('light');
        document.body.classList.add('font-urbanist', 'text-base', 'text-black', 'dark:text-white', 'dark:bg-slate-900');
    });
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <ScrollToTop/>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/index" replace/>}/>
                <Route path="/index" element={<Index/>}/>
                <Route path='/beaches' element={<Beaches/>}/>
                <Route path='/beach/:name' element={<BeachDetail/>}/>
                <Route path='/archaeological-site/:name' element={<ArchaeologicalSiteDetail/>}/>
                <Route path='/tags/:name' element={<TagDetail/>}/>
                <Route path='/gorges' element={<Gorges/>}/>
                <Route path='/gorge/:name' element={<GorgeDetail/>}/>
                <Route path='/archaeological-sites' element={<ArchaeologicalSites/>}/>
                <Route path='/apartments' element={<Apartments/>}/>
                <Route path='/apartment/:name' element={<ApartmentDetail/>}/>
                <Route path='/rules' element={<Rules/>}/>
                <Route path='/activities' element={<Activities/>}/>
                <Route path='/services' element={<Services/>}/>
                <Route path='/faqs' element={<Faqs/>}/>
                <Route path='/privacy' element={<PrivacyPolicy/>}/>
                <Route path='/terms' element={<Terms/>}/>
                <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact/>}/>
                <Route path='*' element={<Error/>}/>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

my src/index.tsx:

```
import React, {Suspense} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import {App} from './App';
import './assets/css/tailwind.css';
import i18next from "i18next";
import {initReactI18next} from "react-i18next";
import I18NextHttpBackend from "i18next-http-backend";
import {LanguageDetector} from "i18next-http-middleware";

i18next
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(I18NextHttpBackend)
    .init({
        lng: localStorage.getItem('lng') || "en",
        fallbackLng: "en",
        detection: {
            order: ['localStorage', 'htmlTag', 'path', 'querystring', 'navigator', 'subdomain'],
            lookupLocalStorage: "lng",
            caches: ['localStorage'],
        },
        backend: {
            loadPath: `/locales/{{lng}}/translation.json`,
        },
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false,
        },
    })
    .then()
    .catch(err => console.error("i18n failed to initialize", err));

let rootElement = document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement;
ReactDOM.hydrateRoot(rootElement,
    <Suspense fallback="loading">
        <React.StrictMode>
            <App/>
        </React.StrictMode>
    </Suspense>
);
```

my server/server.ts:

```
import express, {Application, NextFunction, Request, Response} from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import {renderToString} from 'react-dom/server';
import {createElement} from "react";
import {App} from "../src/App";
import fs from "fs";

const server: Application = express();

server.use('^/$', async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    fs.readFile(path.resolve('./build/index.html'), 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return res.status(500).send('An error occurred');
        }

        console.log(`Request received for ${req.url}`);

        const html = data.replace(
            '<div id="root"></div>',
            `<div id="root">${renderToString(createElement(App))}</div>`
        );
        return res.send(html);
    });
});

server.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')));

server.listen(5001, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${5001}`);
});
```

my .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      {
        "runtime": "automatic"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"
  ]
}
```

when I try to run `npm run ssr` I get the following:

`Error: Cannot find module '../src/App'`

For some reason I cannot make it work no matter what tutorial I found online which is either outdated or wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share your project folder structure. I think it has something to do with your folder structure and your typescript configuration rootDir.